# Laravel Unknown column 'proyectos.id'

Tags: php, sql, laravel, poo

Actualmente tengo un id en una tabla dentro de mi proyecto laravel que trae correctamente la información:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($proyectos as $proyecto)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$proyecto->idProyectos}}</td> 
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('proyectoPreguntasFijas',$proyecto->idProyectos)}}" >
                        PreguntasFijas
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Al presionar editar me dirijo a mi controlador HomeController a través de mi ruta:

```
Route::get('/proyectoPreguntasFijas/{idProyectos}', 'HomeController@proyectoPreguntasFijas')->name('proyectoPreguntasFijas');
Route::post('/proyectoPreguntasFijas/{idProyectos}', 'HomeController@proyectoPreguntasFijas')->name('proyectoPreguntasFijas');
```

En mi controlador HomeController tengo:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Proyecto;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function proyectoPreguntasFijas($idProyectos)
    {
        $proyecto = Proyecto::findOrFail($idProyectos);
        return view('proyectoPreguntasFijas', compact('proyecto'));
    }
}
```

y en mi tabla de base de datos mi id para proyectos es idProyectos.

Si cambio en controlador, ruta, vista y en la tabla de base de datos = $idProyectos y idProyectos por $id y id todo funciona bien, pero si quiero usar "idProyectos" me sale el siguiente error:

> laravel SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'proyectos.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `proyectos` where `proyectos`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

¿Dónde puedo indicar que quiero usar `idProyectos`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cambiar la llave primaria, modifica el atributo/propiedad primaryKey en el modelo:

```
/**
 * The primary key for the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $primaryKey = 'idProyectos';
```

Comment: hey! muchas gracias, laravel no es mi fuerte y donde estoy es basicamente imposible que te respondan una pregunta asi, mcuhas gracias solucionaste mi duda!!! :,D

Comment: por estanda y por ley las llaves primarias son nombrarnos id, no es extraño que el framework de laravel tenga por default el campo id sea primary key

Comment: ay alguna manera de que Laravel ignore el id ya sea el por defecto o el que definimos para buscar por cualquier nombre de columna ?